# Restore fails for a drupal app on openshift

Tags: drupal, openshift

I consistently get failures when trying to restore my drupal app to an openshift gear. The only way I have been able to restore my app is to delete it then recreate the app then add the restore data to the newly created app. It looks like a permissions error.

Anyone else having this issue or have ideas for a solution?

Here is what the process looks like:

```
andy@hermes:~/Siesta Solutions Projects and Files/Marias/Backups$ rhc snapshot restore  mariadaycare -f mariasdaycare.tar.gz
Restoring from snapshot mariasdaycare.tar.gz to application 'mariadaycare' ... 
Error in trying to restore snapshot. You can try to restore manually by running:
cat 'mariasdaycare.tar.gz' | ssh
54034e07e0b8cd2608000659@mariadaycare-siestasolutions.rhcloud.com 'restore
INCLUDE_GIT'
andy@hermes:~/Siesta Solutions Projects and Files/Marias/Backups$ cat 'mariasdaycare.tar.gz' | ssh 54034e07e0b8cd2608000659@mariadaycare-siestasolutions.rhcloud.com 'restore INCLUDE_GIT'
Removing old git repo: ~/git/mariadaycare.git/
Removing old data dir: ~/app-root/data/*
Restoring ~/git/mariadaycare.git and ~/app-root/data
/bin/tar: app-root/data/sites/default/settings.php: Cannot open: Permission denied
/bin/tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.28.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/utils/shell_exec.rb:133:in `block (2 levels) in oo_spawn': Shell command '/bin/tar --strip=2 --overwrite -xmz ./*/app-root/data ./*/app-deployments ./*/git --transform="s|${OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME}/data|app-root/data|" --transform="s|git/.*\.git|git/${OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME}.git|" --exclude="./*/app-root/runtime/data" --exclude="./*/mysql/data" --exclude="./*/php/data" --exclude="./*/phpmyadmin/data" --exclude="./*/cron/data" --exclude="./*/git/*.git/hooks" 1>&2' returned an error. rc=2 (OpenShift::Runtime::Utils::ShellExecutionException)
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.28.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/utils/shell_exec.rb:96:in `pipe'
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.28.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/utils/shell_exec.rb:96:in `block in oo_spawn'
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.28.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/utils/shell_exec.rb:95:in `pipe'
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.28.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/utils/shell_exec.rb:95:in `oo_spawn'
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-container-selinux-0.10.1/lib/openshift/runtime/containerization/selinux_container.rb:368:in `run_in_container_context'
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.28.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_container.rb:795:in `run_in_container_context'
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.28.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_container_ext/snapshots.rb:259:in `extract_restore_archive'
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.28.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_container_ext/snapshots.rb:162:in `restore'
from /usr/bin/gear:585:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:385:in `run_active_command'
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:62:in `run!'
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/delegates.rb:11:in `run!'
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/import.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
andy@hermes:~/Siesta Solutions Projects and Files/Marias/Backups$
```

Comment: can you try running the restore command with the --debug flag

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue many times. One time, it failed and then I login in, change the permission of the settings.php and default/ in the gear (chmod +w, not the snapshot), uploaded the snapshot to the gear and manually restore the snapshot(cat '/path/to/snapshot_file.tar.gz' | oo-restore INCLUDE_GIT). And it worked. I know it seems not logical but maybe you can try.